# Would this be a reasonable use-case for lazy evaluation?

Tags: python, youtube-api

I have a python class called Video, which represents YouTube videos. Given the ID of a YouTube video, Video returns an object representing that video. However, when a Video object is first created, YouTube is not queried. YouTube is only queried once an attribute is asked for that requires information from YouTube. Here's how it works:

```
>>> from video import Video
>>> video = Video('B11msns6wPU') 
# 'B11msns6wPU' is the ID of a video
>>> video
Video(youtube_id="B11msns6wPU")
### As of now, no call to YouTube's API has been made
### Next, I ask for the title attribute. The object queries YouTube's API to get 
### this information. In doing so, the object is completely initialized
>>> video.title
u'Badly Drawn Boy - Disillusion (directed by Garth Jennings)'
>>> video.duration
u'275'
# no query was made to the API because the object has been already been initialized
```

I'm not sure if this is technically "lazy evaluation", but it is similar in flavor. Video objects aren't initialized until the first call for an attribute is made. I'm wondering if this technique was worth implementing. Obviously, it makes my code a bit more complicated. What are your thoughts?

Comment: is there a reason why you chose to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is sort of a general judgement call, not a hard-and-fast decision.

If the lazy object, the `Video` class instance, is central to your application then it might make sense to fully initialize it before doing anything else; if your app is useless without the data, get the data first.

But if your app might have hundreds or thousands of these `Video` instances, and most of them will not be used, it doesn't make sense to make the user wait while you init them all.  In this case, it would make a lot of sense to defer the initialization until it is really needed.  For example, if you will be showing a "wall of thumbnails" display, you might need the thumbnail for each video and the title but you might not need anything else unless the user clicks on a thumbnail.

I do like the general approach, that the code using the object doesn't need to know or care whether the object was pre-initialized or not.

Answer (score 2):

This is `lazy loading`. It's worth implementing if these attributes will not always be needed and it would be a waste to query them from the api for nothing. As in, I create a `Video` class but I don't need those attributes.

Lazy loading is a good idea when Class attributes take a long time to fetch/load. So in your case, is the API call expensive and is it really needed for your `Video` class? More info on the Video class would help see if it's worth implementing. Lazy loading just to lazy load adds complexity to the code for no good reason so yes it is important to see if lazy loading is needed.

At the end of the day it all comes down to *what you do* with the Video object in your application.

Answer (score 1):

[Lazy evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation) (or [lazy loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading), or [lazy initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization)) is useful when **subsequent operations** would otherwise require more queries to the backend, or when a request is so large that it'd be beneficial to do it in chunks, or when there's a good chance that you won't use every part of the request... In general, it's a choice between eager behavior (e.g. `range()` in Python 2.x) and laziness (`range()` in Python 3.x).

In this case, it seems like no matter how the video object is used, in the end all that occurs is a call to the Youtube API for that *single* object.

If your library supported more complex queries or usages, lazy evaluation might be highly useful. Something along the lines of:

```
>>> video_list = ['B11msns6wPU', 'GuaCaMole', 'OvER9000']
>>> videos = Video.fetch(video_list)
# No API call, yet
>>> videos.filter_by('duration', lambda dur: int(dur) > 200)
# Filter by duration - still no API call
>>> for v in videos.all:
...     # Now the API call is made, and the filtering is done all at once
```

Granted, I know that my example was contrived (and it looks oddly like a DB library...), but that's the gist of it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are implementing lazy evaluation and as other answers to the question "is it worth it", it depends on the usage pattern of the data and when you want to make the user wait.  One additional thing to keep in mind is if the pull of the video data might take a while but you are fairly certain that you will need the data, you could pull the data in another thread of execution to prefetch it.

One way implement the type of lazy evaluation you used AND avoid complexity within your code is to use a decorator like @reify in the pyramid library.  Have a look at the @reify decorator in the pyramid library in this [blog entry which contains a link to reify source at the bottom](http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/05/23/python-faq-descriptors/)

This may not be how you want to implement it but it is worth a looking at a "pythonic" solution to lazy evaluation.